# Yeoman command yo not working in windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, web, npm, yeoman

I have installed node and npm. After which I installed yeoman using "npm install -g yo". Later I installed webapp generator using "npm install -g generator-webapp".
Now that everything required was installed I used "yo webapp" command" and "yo" command. Both failed giving me this absurd message

```
C:\Users\***>yo
Node Commands

Syntax:
    node {operator} [options] [arguments]

Parameters:
        /? or /help   - Display this help message.
        list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster
        listcores     - List cores on the cluster
        view          - View properties of a node
        online        - Set nodes or node to online state
        offline       - Set nodes or node to offline state
        pause         - Pause node [deprecated]
        resume        - Resume node [deprecated]

For more information about HPC command-line tools,
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.
```

I cant make head or tail from it. Please help.

Comment: Did you follow these steps : http://creativenotice.com/2013/10/user-yeoman-on-windows-7/ ?

Comment: Yes I did. Yet there was a problem. Later I realized there was a shortcut to cmd that was created by node; now everything works fine when I use that shortcut to launch the console (but there is still a problem when I open the console from the run command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your user path:

```
 C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Then, restart the console.